# "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got -" but why?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have the a table `example1` with 2 datetime columns, these columns does not necessarily have all days (i.e. might not include weekends). I want to create a sequence of days starting from a year ago and get the count of datetimes from table `example1` which occurs on every given day for both columns.

Given a data like this:

```
col1        col2
01/01/2018  01/02/2018
01/02/2018  01/03/2018
01/03/2018  01/05/2018
01/03/2018  NULL
```

the desired ouptput I'm looking is:

```
OnDay      CCol1 CCol2
01/01/2018     1     0
01/02/2018     1     1
01/03/2018     2     1
01/04/2018     0     0
01/05/2018     0     1
```

This is what I've tried but I get this the annoying ORA-00932:

```
WITH all_days (Onday) AS (
    SELECT TRUNC(sysdate) OnDay FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT OnDay-1    FROM all_days
    WHERE Onday > TRUNC(sysdate-365,'Q')
)
SELECT 
    OnDay
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN TRUNC(ex.col1)=OnDay THEN 1 END) CCol1
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN TRUNC(ex.col2)=OnDay THEN 1 END) CCol2
FROM all_days ad
LEFT JOIN example1 ex ON TRUNC(ex.col1)=ad.OnDay OR TRUNC(ex.col2)=ad.OnDay
GROUP BY OnDay
```

Funny enough, the recursive CTE works alone but after plugging the `LEFT JOIN` with the `OR` operator, I get the error that seems to be coming from `SELECT OnDay-1`.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I'm using:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: have you a column  OnDay in your table all_days??

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? I think that is a bug in older versions (pre 12.1)

Comment: I believe there is a bug in the recursive with clause having to deal with nulls..Not sure if it has been fixed

Comment: @Fact This looks like a bug to me but is there a way to deal with it? is there any info from Oracle developers about this bug?

Comment: Sorry I can't of much help to you ..

Comment: Confirmed in MOS, yes this seems to be a bug, fixed in 12.2. There is a patch for previous versions.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Great! do you have a link where to find this info?

Comment: Check `MOS` patch 18139621.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
WITH 
    example1 as
        (
            SELECT To_Date('01.01.2022', 'mm.dd.yyyy') "COL1", To_Date('01.02.2022', 'mm.dd.yyyy') "COL2" FROM Dual
          UNION
            SELECT To_Date('01.02.2022', 'mm.dd.yyyy') "COL1", To_Date('01.03.2022', 'mm.dd.yyyy') "COL2" FROM Dual
          UNION
            SELECT To_Date('01.03.2022', 'mm.dd.yyyy') "COL1", To_Date('01.05.2022', 'mm.dd.yyyy') "COL2" FROM Dual
          UNION
            SELECT To_Date('01.03.2022', 'mm.dd.yyyy') "COL1", Null "COL2" FROM Dual
        ),
    all_days AS  
       (   SELECT TRUNC(To_Date('01.10.2022', 'mm.dd.yyyy'), 'dd') - (LEVEL-1) "ONDAY" FROM Dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10    )
       
SELECT 
    ONDAY,
    Sum(COL1) "COL1",
    Sum(COL2) "COL2"
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            ad.ONDAY,
            CASE WHEN TRUNC(ex.col1)=ad.ONDAY THEN 1 ELSE 0  END Col1,
            CASE WHEN TRUNC(ex.col2)=ad.ONDAY THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Col2
        FROM 
            all_days ad
        LEFT JOIN 
            example1 ex ON(ex.COL1=ad.ONDAY OR ex.COL2=ad.ONDAY)
    )
GROUP BY 
    ONDAY
ORDER BY 
    ONDAY
```

Comment: This is just for 10 days - you can fit it to your needs by adjusting CONNECT BY LEVEL condition.

Comment: Kindly add more details to your answer, explanations on how your code works and how this address the OP's question would be a great help not just for the asker but also for the future researchers.

Comment: Virtual table (cte) called all _days defines starting date and number of consecutive dates you want to check (using LEVEL). Result is a sequence of dates you are checking. Then in the subquery there is Left Join with your data where you put one or zero depending on the Case command. Main select just sums ones and zeros from subquery.

Comment: You can [edit] your answer and add the details.